# How to make first digit autofill to 0 or optional in masked edit extender for textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ok so I am trying to use ajax masked edit extender for time in text box. I want the first digit to be 0 automatically when not entered in textbox. how can you make this happen?. below is my aspx snippet of  masked edit extender. like for example user enters 9:21:12 it should be 09:21:12 automatically in textbox.

```
 <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="mee_FromTime" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxReportFromTime"
                                        Mask="99:99:99" InputDirection="LeftToRight" ClearTextOnInvalid="true" MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
                                        AutoComplete="True" MaskType="Number" />
```

Comment: Try `ClearMaskOnLostFocus` set to true.

Comment: on the `KeyPress` event try to use `PadLeft(8, '0')` in your string and pass it to your TextBox.

Comment: thanks for help guys. I found answer myself below. will try above when I have free time.

Answer (score 1):

Just found answer myself. I used

```
MaskType="Time" UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour"
```

my revised snippet is

```
 <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="mee_FromTime" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxReportFromTime"
                                        Mask="99:99:99" InputDirection="LeftToRight" ClearTextOnInvalid="true" MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
                                        AutoComplete="True" MaskType="Time" UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour"/>
```